# Angular - ViewChild vs document.querySelector

Tags: angular

I searching for the correct way of accessing DOM elements in Angular.

I am working on an example, which requires access to the DOM elements, because I want to change the `offsetTop` and the `scrollTop` properties of my HTMLElements.

I managed to implement my desired feature by querying the DOM elements using `document.querySelector('.my-query-class')` inside `ngAfterViewInit()`. The only issue is that I am querying a div-element, which has a certain CSS class. The div-element, which has this CSS class, changes. This means: There are multiple div-elements, and their CSS class is given by `[ngClass] = {'.my-query-class': condition}`. The condition changes upon clicking onto another div. So, I have to update the assignment `myDOMElement = document.querySelector('.my-query-class')` inside a click-listener. I hope this is more or less clear. In my typescript file I am basically doing the following:

```
myDOMelement?: HTMLElement;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    myDOMElement = document.querySelector('.my-query-class') as HTMLElement;
}

onClick() {
    myDOMElement = document.querySelector('.my-query-class') as HTMLElement;
    if (myDOMElement !== undefined) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Now, even though this works fine, I have a feeling I am not suppossed to solve my problems using `document.querySelector()`. That's why I am looking for an alternative that Angular offers. I have stumbled across the `ViewChild` decorator and tried to implement my feature using it:

```
@ViewChild('.my-query-class') myDOMElementRef?: ElementRef;
myDOMElement?: HTMLElement;

ngAfterInitView() {
    myDOMElement = myDOMElementRef.nativeElement;
}

onClick() {
    if (myDOMElement !== undefined) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

It seems that `myDOMElement` is undefined though. Apparently I don't understand the correct way of using ViewChild. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an angular expert but I have find out that this is a common problem.

View child seems that it works if you use an id.

I let you a code that it works :)

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question4',
  template: `
    <p #idElem class="idElem my-query-class">question4 works!</p>
    <button (click)="onButtonClick()">Button</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./question4.component.sass']
})
export class Question4Component implements AfterViewInit {

  myDOMelement?: HTMLElement;

  constructor() { }

  // @ViewChild('.my-query-class') myDOMElementRef?: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild('idElem') myDOMElementRef?:ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myDOMelement = document.querySelector('.my-query-class') as HTMLElement;
    console.log("this.myDOMElementRef");
    console.log(this.myDOMelement);
    console.log(this.myDOMElementRef);
  }

  onButtonClick(): void {
    console.log("button clicked!!");
    console.log(this.myDOMelement);
    console.log(this.myDOMElementRef);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing an element in Angular using ViewChild, you have to give a template reference to that element.

```
<div #queryElem class="my-query-class"></div>
```

In TS File

```
ViewChild('queryElem', {static: false}) divElem: ElementRef;
```

Also don't access element in ngOnInit hook. Always access DOMElement in ngAfterViewInit.

Refer this doc link to learn about [hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: thx for your answer, @viveksinghal! However, the problem with this is that I have multiple div-elements, and only one of these will be assigned a certain CSS class. The div-element, which will be assigned this CSS class changes upon a click event - when clicking on another div, this div will be assigned the CSS class and the div-element that was assigned the CSS class before will no longer have it. Is it possible to assign a template reference dynamically to an element?